# No tests found for given includes on Spock unit tests for spring boot app

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, groovy, spock

Setting up a new spring boot java project using groovy Spock unit tests in IntelliJ IDEA. I cannot get my first unit test to run. I created it from inside IntelliJ and it is under src/test/groovy.

Here is the unit test.

```
package com.heavyweightsoftware.orders.pojo

import com.heavyweightsoftware.util.FixedDecimal
import spock.lang.Specification

class ItemOrderedTest extends Specification {
    public static final String          ITEM_ID = "OU812"
    public static final String          ITEM_NAME = "Eddie V."
    public static final int             ITEM_QUANTITY = 5
    public static final FixedDecimal    ITEM_UNIT_PRICE = new FixedDecimal(35.62, 2)

    static ItemOrdered getItemOrdered() {
        ItemOrdered result = new ItemOrdered()

        result.itemId = ITEM_ID
        result.quantity = ITEM_QUANTITY
        result.itemName = ITEM_NAME
        result.unitPrice = ITEM_UNIT_PRICE

        return result;
    }

    def "GetQuantity"() {
        given: "A test item"
        ItemOrdered testItem = getItemOrdered()

        when: "Getting Value"
        int result = testItem.quantity

        then: "Should be correct"
        result == ITEM_QUANTITY
    }

    def "GetItemId"() {
        given: "A test item"
        ItemOrdered testItem = getItemOrdered()

        when: "Getting Value"
        String result = testItem.itemId

        then: "Should be correct"
        result == ITEM_ID
    }

    def "GetItemName"() {
        given: "A test item"
        ItemOrdered testItem = getItemOrdered()

        when: "Getting Value"
        String result = testItem.itemName

        then: "Should be correct"
        result == ITEM_NAME
    }

    def "GetLineTotal"() {
        given: "A test item"
        ItemOrdered testItem = getItemOrdered()

        when: "Getting Total"
        FixedDecimal result = testItem.lineTotal

        then: "Should be correct"
        FixedDecimal total = new FixedDecimal(178.10, 2)
        result == total
    }

    def "GetUnitPrice"() {
        given: "A test item"
        ItemOrdered testItem = getItemOrdered()

        when: "Getting Value"
        FixedDecimal result = testItem.unitPrice

        then: "Should be correct"
        result == ITEM_UNIT_PRICE
    }
}
```

Here is the output from when I click on the double arrow in IntelliJ to run the full unit test...

```
Testing started at 12:47 PM ...
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:33391', transport: 'socket'
Gradle Daemon started in 621 ms

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [com.heavyweightsoftware.orders.pojo.ItemOrderedTest](filter.includeTestsMatching)
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.6.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD FAILED in 4s
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:33391', transport: 'socket'
```

and a screenshot of the test setup:

[image]

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.heavyweightsoftware'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // for heavyweight software dependencies
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    // Spock snapshots are available from the Sonatype OSS snapshot repository
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

dependencies {
    // heavyweight software libraries
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'

    // mandatory dependencies for using Spock
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.5"
    testImplementation platform("org.spockframework:spock-bom:2.0-M1-groovy-2.5")
    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-core"
    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-junit4" // you can remove this if your code does not rely on old JUnit 4 rules

    // optional dependencies for using Spock
    testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3" // only necessary if Hamcrest matchers are used
    testImplementation "net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.9.3"          // allows mocking of classes (in addition to interfaces)
    testImplementation "org.objenesis:objenesis:2.6"    // allows mocking of classes without default constructor (together with CGLIB)

    // spring dependencies
    implementation (
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web',
    )

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I have attempted to find all of the issues related to this, but none of them seemed to help. It doesn't seem to be finding my source code of the unit test.

Comment: Show your Gradle dependencies. In particular, Spock 1 generates JUnit 4 annotations, and Spock 2 generates JUnit 5; your test runner may not match your Spock version.

Comment: (As a note, you'll be more productive if you can adopt Groovy's convenience features. One main one is eliminating the need for "temporary variables" like in your builder method: `return new ItemOrdered(itemId: ITEM_ID, quantity: ITEM_QUANTITY, itemName: ITEM_NAME, unitPrice: ITEM_UNIT_PRICE)`.)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I think you mean from my build.gradle file. I have copied in those values.

Comment: Remove the `spock-junit4` dependency and see if it works. Note that you're explicitly excluding the "Vintage" engine, which is the JUnit 5 engine that can execute JUnit 4 tests (I believe this is generated by default from Spring Initializr).

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-Good idea, but after change and refresh, same exact results.

Comment: Try the hardcore option: `javap` the test's class file and see exactly what annotations are listed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I am a 100% Maven user. Gradle for me is more like trial & error. But I am interested in Spock questions, so I am giving it a shot.*

You need to add the Groovy plugin to your build file:

```java
plugins {
  // ...
  id 'java'
  id 'groovy'
}
```

This will also help IDEA to recognise that this is a Groovy project and you can run tests from `src/test/groovy`.

Next, you will get test compilation errors because there is an obvious mismatch between you using

- `org.spockframework:spock-bom:2.0-M1-groovy-2.5` vs.
- `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.5`,

i.e.

- a Spock version for Groovy 2.5
- but Groovy 3.

So either you downgrade Groovy or upgrade Spock. Besides, M1 is not up to date, better use M3.

```java
  // mandatory dependencies for using Spock
  testCompile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.5.13"
  testImplementation platform("org.spockframework:spock-bom:2.0-M3-groovy-2.5")
```

Now your test should compile and run. I did not check the test as such, though. I cannot run it anyway without the classes under test.

Getting rid of the `org.spockframework:spock-junit4` dependency is optional. As was said before, Spock 2.x is based on JUnit 5, so if you do not have any legacy Spock tests in your project using JUnit 4 features like `@RunWith` for PowerMock or similar ugly stuff, you do not need it.

Maybe you want to change your build file to be more similar to the one in the [Spock sample project](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/blob/master/build.gradle).

---

**Update 2021-07-20:** I just opened this example project again in order to answer [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68446134/1082681). In doing do, I noticed that you need to be careful when using something like `sourceCompatibility = '11'`, but running the build on an older JDK like 8. It will cause the following, counter-intuitive Gradle error:

```
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [com.heavyweightsoftware.orders.pojo.ItemOrderedTest](filter.includeTestsMatching)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Only when running the test with Gradle parameter `--debug`, you will see the root cause (log labels and timestamps deleted):

```
Gradle Test Executor 31 FAILED
    org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not execute test class 'com.heavyweightsoftware.orders.pojo.ItemOrderedTest'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:53)
        (...)

        Caused by:
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/heavyweightsoftware/orders/pojo/ItemOrderedTest has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            (...)
```

Comment: This seems to have done it. I added the groovy plugin (sorry I didn't notice, Spring built this one for me" and then noticed my src/test/groovy folder wasn't marked as test source. I marked it and then ran the test and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, you don't mark it manually if you want to make sure that the Gradle build file is correct! You manually or automatically re-import the Gradle build and see if IDEA recognises the source folder automatically. Gradle should always be the leading system. Your IDEA build would be unreliable if you had to do additional customising which later might be overwritten by a Gradle re-import again. Then on the next workstation your co-worker starts wondering why on your machine the build runs but not on hers. So don't do that stuff!

Comment: **Update 2021-07-20:** I am also explaining, why sometimes `No tests found for given includes` can occur without any obvious reason.

Comment: src/test/groovy is the key

Answer (score 4):

For me worked this solution. Just remove:

```
test {
   useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'org.yourcompany.common.dataflow.plugin' version '0.1.13'
    id 'com.github.jk1.dependency-license-report' version '1.16'
}

group = 'org.yourcompany.dataflow'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://nexus.yourcompany.ru:8081/repository/maven-public/"
    }
}
ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2020.0.1")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'


    // third party
    compile 'io.dgraph:dgraph4j:20.11.0'


    // yourcompany
    implementation 'org.yourcompany:common_dataflow_annotations:0.1.11'
    implementation('org.yourcompany:common_service:0.2.27') {
        exclude group: 'io.springfox', module: 'springfox-swagger2'
    }


    // test and dev
    testCompile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.5.6'
    testImplementation group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.3-groovy-2.5'
    testImplementation group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-spring', version: '1.3-groovy-2.5'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding the following works for me like Alex mentioned above.

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.8'
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-groovy-3.0'
}
```