# Unable to run Spock tests after upgrading to 2.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spock

I'm trying to upgrade a Spring Boot (2.1.4.RELEASE) project from Spock 1.3 to 2.0. Unfortunately, I'm getting `No tests found for given includes:` for any test I try to run. Here is a `build.gradle` snippet with what I hope are all the relevant parts:

```
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.0'
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'

// enabling spock - the bdd
testImplementation(
    "org.spockframework:spock-core",
    "org.spockframework:spock-spring:${spockGroovyVersion}",
    "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.8",
    "io.github.http-builder-ng:http-builder-ng-apache:1.0.4",
    platform("org.spockframework:spock-bom:${spockGroovyVersion}")
)

// Provides JUnit, Spring Test, AssertJ, Hamcrest, Mockito, JSONassert, & JsonPath
testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
    // don't include JUnit 4 (needed until spring-boot-starter-test:2.2.0 is supported)
    exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I get the same result whether `useJUnitPlatform()` is present or commented out.

Comment: I assume, `${spockGroovyVersion}` is exactly `2.0-groovy-3.0`? BTW, you do need `useJUnitPlatform()` for Spock 2, please do not comment it out. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing the problem on GitHub would be helpful.

Comment: BTW, do you have `plugins { id 'java'; id 'groovy' }` in your Gradle config? Without the Groovy plugin, no tests can be found.

Comment: I also just remember that I saw the same error before, when using something like `sourceCompatibility = '11'`, but running the build on an older JDK like 8. I just updated my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64272744/1082681). If that solves your problem, please let me know.

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed that one variable. It is indeed exactly `2.0-groovy-3.0`.

I am unfortunately unable to provide an MCVE as this is a work project, and it could well take longer to disentangle unrelated code than to stumble upon a fix without an MCVE.

With respect to plugins, I have `apply plugin: 'groovy'`, no Java plugin.

The only Java version line I see is `javaConfig.targetVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`

Comment: Then you should have said "would be required" rather than "would be helpful".

Comment: @spartanhooah take a look at https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example and try to compare it to your project.